# Show per-column aggregations for each Group in Ag-Grid Angular with 'groupRows' grouping

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, ag-grid-grouping

I'm currently using Ag-Grid in my Angular project to group rows based on a specific column. I've set the groupDisplayType to 'groupRows' for this purpose.

However, I'm facing an issue where I need to display aggregation values for each group per column in my Ag-Grid configuration. Essentially, I want to show the aggregation results in the group headers, as shown in the red numbers in the attached image.

Here's the code I'm working with: Plunker link
https://plnkr.co/edit/XXr5Ys85QRGcRWBk?open=app%2Fapp.component.ts

I would greatly appreciate any assistance in achieving this functionality. Thank you in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is something which can be done using [Configuring Group Cell Renderer](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/grouping-group-rows/#configuring-group-cell-renderer) approach.

Here's a working example from the official docs: https://plnkr.co/edit/?open=app%2Fapp.component.ts&preview

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ICellRendererAngularComp } from 'ag-grid-angular';
import { GroupCellRendererParams, IRowNode } from 'ag-grid-community';

interface GroupRowParams extends GroupCellRendererParams {
  flagCodes: Record<string, string>;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'group-row-cell',
  template: ` <div class="row">
    <img
      *ngIf="flagCode"
      class="flag"
      border="0"
      width="20"
      height="15"
      [src]="flagCodeImg"
    />
    <span class="groupTitle">{{ node.key }}</span>
    <span
      class="medal gold"
      attr.aria-label="{{ node.key }} - {{ node.aggData.gold }} gold medals"
      ><i class="fas fa-medal"></i>{{ node.aggData.gold }}</span
    >
    <span
      class="medal silver"
      attr.aria-label="{{ node.key }} - {{ node.aggData.silver }} silver medals"
      ><i class="fas fa-medal"></i>{{ node.aggData.silver }}</span
    >
    <span
      class="medal bronze"
      attr.aria-label="{{ node.key }} - {{ node.aggData.bronze }} bronze medals"
      ><i class="fas fa-medal"></i>{{ node.aggData.bronze }}</span
    >
  </div>`,
  styles: [
    `
      .row {
        display: inline-block;
      }

      .groupTitle {
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: bold;
      }

      .medal {
        margin: 0 5px;
      }

      .gold {
        color: #e4ab11;
      }

      .silver {
        color: #bbb4bb;
      }

      .bronze {
        color: #be9088;
      }

      .flag {
        margin: 0 4px;
        position: relative;
        top: 2px;
      }
    `,
  ],
})
export class GroupRowInnerRenderer implements ICellRendererAngularComp {
  public flagCodeImg!: string;
  public flagCode!: any;
  public node!: IRowNode;

  agInit(params: GroupRowParams): void {
    this.node = params.node;
    this.flagCode = params.flagCodes[params.node.key || ''];
    this.flagCodeImg = `https://flags.fmcdn.net/data/flags/mini/${this.flagCode}.png`;
  }

  refresh(): boolean {
    return false;
  }
}
```

The example can be tweaked for the desired result